# Paging dynamically loaded Webix tree nodes

Tags: javascript, tree, webix

Is there a way to page through child nodes of a Webix tree? The root-level elements are known, but their children should be loaded dynamically via an AJAX call. For example, given a list of GitHub users, I want to retrieve the repos of each - [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/526c5ab4).

The documentation suggests a `pager` property, but it's unclear how to use it, or [dynamic loading](https://github.com/webix-hub/tracker/issues/181) with [hybrid tree structures](http://forum.webix.com/discussion/comment/3584/#Comment_3584) (local + remote), or [dataFeed as a function](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.tree_datafeed_config.html).

If this is possible, then Webix has a nice advantage over [Kendo UI, which can't page through tree nodes](http://www.telerik.com/forums/paging-a-treeview).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different features

a) dynamic data loading

tree can use dynamical loading, when you are loading part of data initially and rest of data will be loaded automatically when related branch is expanded.

http://webix.com/snippet/91f765c8

In above sample, some nodes has "webix_kids" attribute that forces new data requests on related branch opening.

b) paging

It is more common for plain components ( lists and grids ) but can be used with treetable as well ( it is side effect of cross compatibility between webix components)

In paging mode you can see only slice of dataset, one page of data.

http://webix.com/snippet/69e0b5ea

Comment: that's not what DanDascalescu is asking. He is asking a solution for DYNAMIC paging for both child and parent nodes at the same time.